# Where to get cgidemo of vnstat?

Tags: gui, bandwidth

I have installed vnstat and now I would like to have statistics in my browser like this:

[image]

You can see working script [here](http://humdi.net/vnstat/cgidemo/). Where can I get that cgidemo script?

Source: http://humdi.net/vnstat/

Answer (score 2):

[Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/a/104060/161) is right, `vnstati` generates images. But there is a script also which is written in Perl and uses `vnstati`. I have found that script after downloading source code of vnstat from [here](http://humdi.net/vnstat/vnstat-1.11.tar.gz). It is called `vnstat.cgi` and is located under the folder called `examples`. You need just configure webserver to run cgi and it outputs the same images as in http://humdi.net/vnstat/cgidemo/ page.

Comment: Excellent.Did not think to download the source :( ah well :D

Comment: The author of `vnstat` has also uploaded its source code to GitHub, so can directly download the script from there: https://github.com/vergoh/vnstat/blob/master/examples/vnstat.cgi (It is currently still the same version as in the 1.11 tarball you linked to.)

Answer (score 1):

You make the images with the command [`vnstati`](http://humdi.net/vnstat/man/vnstati.html). From the link:

**Description**

> The purpose of vnstati is to provide image output support for statistics collected using vnstat(1). The image file format is limited to png. All basic outputs of vnStat are supported excluding live traffic features. The image can be outputted either to a file or to standard output.

**Synopsis**

```
vnstati [ -cdhimostv? ] [ --cache time ] [ --config file ] [ --days ] [ --dbdir directory ] 
[ --help ] [ --hours ] [ -hs ] [ --hsummary ] [ -i interface ] [ --iface interface ] 
[ --locale locale ] [ --months ] [ -ne ] [ -nh ] [ --noedge ] [ --noheader ] 
[ --output file ] [ -ru ] [ --rateunit ] [ --style number ] [ --summary ] 
[ --top10 ] [ --transparent ] [ --version ] [ -vs ] [ --vsummary ]
```

**Examples**

```
vnstati -s -i eth0 -o /tmp/vnstat.png
```

Output traffic summary for interface eth0 to file `/tmp/vnstat.png`.

```
vnstati -vs -i eth0+eth1+eth2 -o /tmp/vnstat.png
```

Output traffic summary with hourly data under the normal summary for a merge of interfaces eth0, eth1 and eth2 to file `/tmp/vnstat.png`.

```
vnstati -h -c 15 -o /tmp/vnstat_h.png
```

Output hourly traffic statistics for default interface to file `/tmp/vnstat_h.png` if the file has not been updated within the last 15 minutes.

```
vnstati -d -ne -nh -o -
```

Output daily traffic statistics without displaying the header section and edges for default interface to standard output (`stdout`).

```
vnstati -m --config /home/me/vnstat.cfg -i -o -
```

Output monthly traffic statistics for default interface specified in configuration file `/home/me/vnstat.cfg` to standard output (`stdout`).